# android why setbackgroundresource can't show the background picture

Tags: android

i use setbackgroundresource to set the background of LinearLayout, but it cant show in the activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);       
        sp = getSharedPreferences("config", MODE_PRIVATE);
        bgpic = sp.getInt("bgpic", 3);
        ll_main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
        Log.i(TAG, "图片"+imageIds[bgpic]);
        Log.i(TAG, "图片"+R.drawable.bg2);
        ll_main.setBackgroundResource(imageIds[bgpic]);
        ll_main.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

above is part of the code.

Comment: remove the last line and it should work. You are adding a empty drawable over a res. That's why you dont see a BG i think.

Comment: Remove this line **ll_main.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());** and check again

Comment: I remove the last line , but i dosen't work yet. i make my freinds to have a look,they can't resolve the problem.i dont know if there are any factor can effect it,or it is just the emulator's problem.